# numpy multi-dimensional selecton with 2D indexing

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I am confused with below cases:

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 32, 3, 64);

print(x.shape)

#(1, 32, 3, 64)
```

Then I apply this selection.

```
y = x[np.arange(1)[:, None], :, 1,  np.arange(64)[None, :]]
```

I think i selected all rows in dimension 0, 1, 3 , the 1 in 2nd dimension should be exception.. but it gave

```
print(y.shape)

#(1, 64, 32)
```

for below case:

```
y = x[np.arange(1)[:, None], :, [1],  np.arange(64)[None, :]]
```

I think i selected all rows in 0, 1 dimension, and always use the 1st row in 2 dimension.

```
print(y.shape)

#(1, 64, 32)
```

Why the shape become this (1, 64, 32) in both cases?

And what is the difference of 1 and [1]?

Answer (score 0):

Can you maybe give a bit more context on what you are trying to achieve?  Is there a specific reason you are indexing with `np.arange(1)[:, None]` instead of just `:`? e.g. is `y = x[:,:,1,:]` shape:(1,32,64) not what you are looking for?

The 1 vs. [1] indexing difference looks like it could be advanced indexing: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: AI, deep learning, reading code. why the shape become (1, 32, 3, 64) to (1, 64, 32)? thanks.